# Including additional rules with flex

Tags: include, lex

I've been working on a small assembler which uses flex, however, the flex rule list is reasonably long.  Ideally, I'd like to solve this by splitting the rules into several files which can be included into the primary lex file.  My searching has turned up nothing of relevance which leads me to believe this functionality may not exist.  If it doesn't exist I'd be curious if anybody had some alternate suggestions.  My only current alternate is to write a quick tool which preprocesses the lex file and builds a new one.  This isn't the prettiest solution, but I suppose it does work.

So this question boils down to two questions:

1. Is there a way to include additional rules with flex?
2. If not, what alternates would you suggest (if they are different from the one I already proposed)?

I am not strictly against moving to a different lexer if one has a compelling reason to do so.  However, in such cases, the lexer needs to be able to generate C or C++, either can be merged into this project with ease.  I do consider this option to be a last resort though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've been playing with various solutions for awhile now and finally have one I am particularly happy with.  I ended up using bash to quickly implement a "flex_include" script.

Before I explain the syntax additions here is the script I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
if [[ $line =~ "<<INCLUDE>>".* ]]; then
    file=$(echo $line | cut -d'"' -f2)
    while read -r line2
    do
        echo "$line2"
    done < $file
else
    echo "$line"
fi
done < $1
```

This allows for including files with the syntax `<<INCLUDE>> "my_file.l"` within your lex file.  I choose a naming convention similar to that of `<<EOF>>` and thus it fits into the flex syntax reasonably well.  Usage of the script is reasonably simple, but there is a caveat -- pipes don't directly work.  I don't know why but two extra lines would be generated in `lex.yy.c` at the top. I found process substitution worked just fine though: `flex <(./flex_include.sh mips.l)`.  This script is very forgiving in syntax, so just keep in mind that the script will accept more than it should.  It will search for a single line with `<<INCLUDE>>` and then match a quoted string on that line, everything else is ignored and deleted on that line.

Answer (score 2):

`flex` certainly doesn't include any functionality similar to the C preprocessor `#include` directive.

Also, using the C preprocessor to preprocess scanner definitions would be a bit awkward because scanner descriptions commonly include preprocessor commands to be transcribed into the output file, and the C preprocessor doesn't have any mechanism to conditionally retain directives.

However, there is nothing stopping your from simply concatenating several files to produce a scanner definition:

```
flex -o scanner.c scanner.options scanner.definitions keyword_rules.l other_rules.l
```

Comment: Thats pretty handy, I just came up with a similar solution but I like yours more. I was going to use something like `flex <(cat mips.start.l) <(cat mips.r4300.l) <(cat mips.end.l)`.  Sadly, an include mechanism would allow for two files but both of these approaches require three to ensure proper order.  I'm going to play around with some ideas for a moment, but if I come up with nothing better I will accept this :).  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, I'll be sure to keep it in mind for other potential uses, but I've gone ahead with a different solution that provided a better overall syntax.  You can see my solution in the answer I posted.